# Trying to ensure that both password fields have the same value and aren't blank Java Script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a script that validates an email textbox and ensure that both password fields have the same value and are not blank. I am having trouble trying to make sure the requirements are met but am having no luck I am very new to JS so any help would be great. This is what I have so far.

```
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  let error = "";
  const emailPattern =/\w+@\w+\.\w+/;
  password1=document.querySelector('#pass').value;
  password2=document.querySelector('#pass2').value;
  
  if(email.match(emailPattern))
  {
    console.log("vaild");
    return true;
  }
  else if(email === "")
  {
    error = "You entered a blank email address. \n";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
   else if(email != email.match(emailPattern))
  {
    error = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
  if(password1.match(password2))
  {
    console.log("vaild");
    return true;
  }
  else if(password1 != password2)
  {
    error= "The passwords do not match";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
  else if(password1 && password2 === "")
  {
    error = "You entered a blank password";
    alert(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statements are taking you out of your validation function, that's why it stops at the first validation.

I would do something like this:

```
  const pass = document.querySelector('#pass');
const passC = document.querySelector('#pass2');

document.querySelector('#submitButton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (email === "") {
        error = "You entered a blank email address. \n";
        alert(error);
    } else if (email != email.match(emailPattern)) {
        error = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
        alert(error);
    }

    if(pass.value.trim() === '' || passC.value.trim() === '' ){
        console.log('You entered a blank password')
        alert(error);
    }else if(pass.value.trim() !== passC.value.trim()){
        error= "The passwords do not match";
        alert(error);
    }
    

    if(email.match(emailPattern) && pass.value.trim() === passC.value.trim()){
        console.log('all information is valid')
    }

})
```

If you want the function to stop at the first not met condition you should add the "return false" at every if statement except the one that if passed will continue to submit the form (the last one) in this case, return true as you wrote before.

Comment: I understand the click on EventListener but what I don't fully understand is the (e)  => is that my function I am declaring in the parameters?

Comment: The ()=>{ } it's an arrow function. The "e" it's the event and it's only purpose here is to prevent it form refreshing the page. I'don't know if you are using ajax (that's why I use prevent default) or maybe you have your method and action set on your html, in which case you shouldn't use the line "e.preventDefault()"

Comment: I am not using ajax just vanilla JS. Therefore I can remove the preventDefault method and it won't affect my original action set in my HTML?

Comment: yes, correct. You would need to add the eventlistener to your submit button and change the variables you need